# transferring data from one database to another keeps dying

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have 2 databases and I am trying to transfer data from one to another. I am doing this with PHP and MySQLi because I need to manipulate some of the data as I do this. A couple things that The database as a whole is over 15GB. I set max execution time and set timeout to 0 ( no limit ) and have tried a few different things but it keeps dying about 10% in. I feel like it is timing out but I have set the correct parameters. It Ran on my last try, ripping 50,000 rows at a time, for 90 some odd minutes before dying. Because of the way its dying it isn't echoing out any error data. These are also two different DB connections I am using.

I am looking for some feedback on the best way to do this because the way I am doing it isn't working entirely.

Comment: Do you run it from the command line or over the net?

Comment: I have tried both same result

Comment: please provide a minimized variant of your code, that still exposes the same behavior.

Comment: At least on the command line you should see the errors; if not, include `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script. Trying to run scripts like that over the net is generally a bad idea, since it is not intended for that. Output some summarizing data (for example how many rows processed) into a log file or table so you can see where it fails.

Comment: Check the MySQL error log - perhaps it says "MySQL Server has gone away"? See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html

Also you should put try/catch blocks around your actions to figure out what happens when the script crashes...

Comment: Bulk-processing scripts should also include `ignore_user_abort(TRUE);` at the top of the script, so that the script will not die if you log out or connection is lost and it tries to write to the STDOUT.

Comment: And it may be useful to use `flush()` or [output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to see the complete output of your script.